# PostgreSQL- getColumnName is not working, returning alias Name

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to get the column name from below query,

```
SELECT
    category as c1,
    forecast_2016,
    category,
    rowcount,
    item_number,
    rowcount,
    category,
    avg_demand_2014_2015,
    category,
    avg_spend_2014_2015,
    avg_demand_2014_2015,
    avg_spend_2014_2015,
    demand_2015
FROM
    ag_instrument_portfolio_master LIMIT 1
```

Postgres version is 9.3 and Java version 1.7, java implementation is below.

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query.toString());
ResultSetMetaData columnsMetadata = rs.getMetaData();
int i = 0;
while (i < columnsMetadata.getColumnCount()) {
    i++;
    System.out.println("Name: " + columnsMetadata.getColumnName(i));
    System.out.println("Label: " + columnsMetadata.getColumnLabel(i));
}
```

The output is

```
Name: c1
Label: c1
```

But, expected is

```
Name: category
Label: c1
```

Comment: Change `SELECT category as c1` to `SELECT category`

Comment: That is the correct column name. It's defined as that in your SQL. As far as Java is concerned, that IS the column name. You'll need to change the query in this case to return category instead of c1.

Comment: @Nicarus, i purposefully given the alias to reduce the json size, my records will be in million

Comment: Then why are you expecting `category` as the column name if you knowingly aliased it as `c1`?

Comment: So you purposely prevent `getColumnName()` from delivering the longer name. You have to choose which you want, the short column name or the long one.

Comment: @Nicarus, i wanted to construct query to group by using metdata, select category as c1, number as y from table to select category, sum(number) as y from table group by category

Comment: You can group by the aliases. No need for the original column names. It's also worth noting that you are returning the same data back multiple times e.g. category is returned 4 times! This is not the way you should be doing this. You should be returning back the raw data ONCE and reusing it as necessary in your client.

Comment: @ManoDestra That is not how it is supposed to work: JDBC specifies that `getColumnName` should return the original column name (if available), the `AS` label should be returned from `getColumnLabel`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel See the given answer by Gord Thomson. What we may consider intuitively true does not naturally follow. We are at the mercy of the driver, I'm afraid. If the OP wants the column to be known as "category", then he should return it as such. It's the only way to guarantee it. You can't depend on the driver doing the right thing, unfortunately.

Comment: @ManoDestra That may be true, but based on the JDBC API and specification the expectation of the OP is correct; I was responding to your claim that this expectation is somehow weird or wrong.

Comment: Agreed, but it is up to each vendor. And they are not doing that. It is simply not guaranteed behavior and cannot be relied on implicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the comment in the `pgsql-jdbc` mailing list [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3DFE22C8.7000006@xythos.com), it appears that what you're seeing is the "as designed" behaviour of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver:

> This is a limitation of the information the driver gets back from the 
>   server, it only returns the 'label' which the driver then uses for both 
>   columnname and label.

As with many other aspects of JDBC, the behaviour of a given feature can often vary depending on the implementation of a specific JDBC driver.